# Django auto-populating form field from API call

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am trying to auto-populate one field of a Django form based on the query response of an entry into another field. I would like to do so before the form is submitted, displaying the autopopulated value in the field and maintain the user's ability to edit.

(Example, I type 'a handful of bananas' into the name field, when that field blurs it queries the api and fills the carbs field with the # of carbs a handful of bananas has)

Right now I have the ajax function to query:

```
$('#recipe-query').on('blur', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("blur")
    query_macros();
});

function query_macros(){
    var dataStr =  "APIKEYREDACTED"
    var ingredParam = encodeURI($('#recipe-query').val())
    dataStr = dataStr + ingredParam
    if($('#recipe-query').val() && $('#should-query').val()){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data",
            data: dataStr,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",

            success : function(json){
                console.log(json);
                console.log(json.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity)
                $('#carbs-query').value = json.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity;

            },

            error : function(xhr, errmsg, err){
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is the form

```
class NutritionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Nutrition
        fields = ('food_name', 'autofill_macros', 'grams_of_fat',
                  'grams_of_protein', 'grams_of_carbs', 'date')
        widgets = {
            'food_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'recipe-query'
            }),
            'autofill_macros': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
                'id': 'should-query'
            }),
            'grams_of_fat': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'fat-query'
            }),
            'grams_of_protein': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'protein-query'
            }),
            'grams_of_carbs': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'carbs-query'
            })
        }
```

and model

```
class Nutrition(models.Model):
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    autofill_macros = models.BooleanField()
    grams_of_protein = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    grams_of_carbs = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    grams_of_fat = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    calories = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but the `#carbs-query` field is not updated. How do I use the result of the API call to populate the other field while maintaining its editability (all before form submit).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like js code have some issues. you can try below method of jQuery to set value:

```
$('#carbs-query').val(json.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity);
```

Full code:

```
function query_macros(){
    var dataStr =  "APIKEYREDACTED"
    var ingredParam = encodeURI($('#recipe-query').val())
    dataStr = dataStr + ingredParam
    if($('#recipe-query').val() && $('#should-query').val()){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data",
            data: dataStr,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",

            success : function(json){
                console.log(json);
                console.log(json.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity)
                $('#carbs-query').val(json.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity);


            },

            error : function(xhr, errmsg, err){
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```